# Как вставить строчку изменяющуюся в зависимости от времени

Tags: php, javascript

На сайт хочется вставить строку.

Если юзер на сайте в промежутке с 8:00 до 13:00, то должно быть написано:

*Доставка с 8 до 17 (тут дата завтрашнего дня)*

Если же с 13:00 до 19:00 то:
*Доставка с 8 до 17 (тут дата послезавтрашнего дня)*

Время по Москве.
Подскажите как реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var today= new Date(),
    tomorrow = new Date(),
    dayaftertomorrow = new Date();
    
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
dayaftertomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+2);

if (today.getHours() >= 8 && today.getHours() <= 13) {
  console.log( "Доставка с 8 до 17 ("+ ("0" + tomorrow.getDate()).slice(-2) + "." + ("0" + (tomorrow.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "." + tomorrow.getFullYear() + ")");
} else {
  console.log( "Доставка с 8 до 17 ("+ ("0" + dayaftertomorrow.getDate()).slice(-2) + "." + ("0" + (dayaftertomorrow.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "." + dayaftertomorrow.getFullYear() + ")");
}
```